# Got a error message for the command "mongo --port 27003"

Tags: mongodb, macos

Got `errno:61 Connection refused`  when I type `mongo --port 27003` on mac osx terminal

but simply `mongo` it's working fine

Answer (score 0):

By default mongod runs on 27017 port.

When you type "mongo" it connects to that port and not 27003.

Try this "mongo --port 27017"

If you want to run mongod on a different port

Open : /etc/mongodb.conf

Change

```
 port: 27003
```

Restart mongod service

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Comment: but I wanted to connect the port 27003

Comment: @Kuhan Do you know on which port is your mongod running?

Comment: @Kuhan Or Do you want to run your mongod on 27003 and then connect to it?

Comment: I want to run mongod on the port 27003